# How to Restrict the Spring IOC container to create my custom object using private constructor

Tags: java, spring

As we know that , spring ioc can create an object of class whose constructor is declared even as private by using reflection.
If ioc do so, then why not ioc is able to create an object of java.util.Calendar class. It will only create by using getInstance() method.

```
<bean id="cal" class="java.util.Calendar" factory-method="getInstance" />
```

but it won't create

```
  <bean id="cal" class="java.util.Calendar"/>
```

As per my understanding,the reason is, in getInstance() method may be calendar class prepare some current date time data to return etc. thats why Calendar class does not allow to create an object of Calendar class by using constructor[so declared as private]. It is only possible via getInstance() method.

but for my own class if constructor is declared as private

```
**case 1.** <bean id="s" class="bean.Student">  <!--want to restrict in this case like Calendar.class-->
**case-2.** <bean id="s" class="bean.Student" factory-method="getInstance">
```

Spring ICO is able to create an object of Student.class by using reflection.
Now my question is, I want to restrict the spring ICO to create an object of Student.class in **case 1.** like Calendar.class. How I can achieve this target? Please help 
Here is My Student.class code

```
package bean;
public class Student {

    public static  Student student = null;

private Student() { 
        System.out.println("default constructor");
    }

public static Student getInstance() {
    System.out.println("factory method called");
    if(student == null) {
        student = new Student();
    }
    return student;
}
}
```

Comment: @theBlackBencher, you should consider using Java configuration classes, instead of XML configuration files. The former has so much advantages over the later!

Answer (score 1):

you wont be able to prevent object creation via reflection ( even class have private constructor).

The java.util.Calendar is an abstract class( see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) ). Hence direct object creation for this class is not possible, the generator method ( getInstance() ) creates and returns the concrete class object.

Considering the above description, you can also make your class abstract and provide object generator method. This way the IOC of spring wont be able to create instance of your class. It can create instance of concrete classes only(using reflection).